# Join query with only columns that have all values in `in` clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I'm creating a simple filtering system for my website. I have a many to many relationship between venues and amenities. Here are my tables.

NOTE: all ids are uuids. Making them short for simplicity

venues:

```
| id    |      name      |
_________________________
| 'aaa' |  'first venue' |
| 'bbb' | 'second venue' |
| 'ccc' | 'third venue'  |
```

amenities:

```
| id    |      name        |
___________________________
| 'aaa' |  'first amenity' |
| 'bbb' | 'second amenity' |
| 'ccc' | 'third amenity'  |
```

amenity_venue:

```
| amenity_id  |    venue_id  |
______________________________
| 'aaa'       |  'aaa'       |
| 'bbb'       | 'aaa'        |
| 'ccc'       | 'aaa'        |
| 'aaa'       | 'bbb'        |
| 'bbb'       | 'ccc'        |
```

I'm trying to write a query to return the venues that have at least all the passed in amenity_ids. For example passing in amenity_ids `aaa` and `bbb`.

Output I'm looking for when the amenity ids passed in are `aaa` and `bbb`.

```
| id    |      name      |
_________________________
| 'aaa' |  'first venue' |
```

Initially I tried this query

```
select * from venues 
INNER JOIN amenity_venue ON amenity_venue.venue_id = venues.id
where amenity_id in ('aaa', 'bbb');
```

This returns all the venues that have either amenity_id `aaa` or `bbb`

```
| id    |      name      |
_________________________
| 'aaa' |  'first venue' |
| 'bbb' | 'second venue' |
| 'ccc' | 'third venue'  |
```

so then naively I tried

```
select * from venues 
INNER JOIN amenity_venue ON amenity_venue.venue_id = venues.id
where amenity_id = 'aaa'
  and amenity_id = 'bbb';
```

Which returns nothing. I'm trying to write a query where if amenity_ids `aaa` and `bbb` are passed in only venue `aaa` is returned since its the only venue that has a relationship with both amenities. Also the number of amenities is dynamic from query to query.

Comment: share your output

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result? (BTW, 'aaa' is easy to read, but '0cbe0352-89b6-4ed5-8a4e-b8127d32b5b3' is not.)

Comment: Do WHERE IN (amenity id list). GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT = number of amenities.

Comment: @jarlh could you share an answer with the example?

Comment: @user10457989 be sure to accept an answer now people have given you working solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by aggregating the IDs into an array and then compare that with the list of intended IDs:

```
select v.*
from venues v
  join amenity_venue av ON av.venue_id = v.id
group by v.id
having array_agg(av.amenity_id) @> array['aaa', 'bbb'];
```

The above assumes that `venue.id` is declared as the primary key (because of the `group by`).

You don't really need to hardcode the IDs in the query if you would like to just pass the amenity names:

```
select v.*
from venues v
  join amenity_venue av ON av.venue_id = v.id
group by v.id
having array_agg(av.amenity_id) @> array(select id 
                                         from amenities 
                                         where name in ('first amenity', 'second amenity'));
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/FNNVXO34389

Comment: Do I need to typecast for uuids?

Comment: @user10457989: yes for the array literal: `array['...', '...']::uuid[]`

Comment: @user10457989: I have updated the online example to use UUIDs

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select * from venues 
where  exists (
    select venue_id from amenity_venue 
    where venues.id = amenity_venue.venue_id and amenity_id in ('aaa', 'bbb')
    group by venue_id
    having count(*) = 2
  )
```

[Working Solution](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a2qpUJKuWKGwvSk7wwgTgy/0)

Comment: thanks for the answer; however, this still returns all the venues that have either 'aaa' or 'bbb'. One upgrade though with this query is that it "groups" venues.

Comment: I updated my query accordingly. Can you check again?

Comment: This now returns no venues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
SELECT v.*
FROM venues v
WHERE v.name IN (/* list of venues names */)
  AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM amenities AS a
         WHERE a.name IN (/* list of amenity names */)
           AND NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM amenity_venue AS av
                  WHERE av.venut_id = v.id
                    AND av.amenity_id = a.id
               )
      );
```

That should work independent of how many amenities there are.

You can add conditions in the places I indicated to limit the query to only a certain subset of amenities or venues.

Comment: Where do I pass in the `amenity_ids`?

Comment: I have extended the answer to show where conditions can be added.

Comment: I tried this query. Same as your query without the `v.name in` clause. `SELECT v.*
FROM venues v
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM amenities AS a
         WHERE a.name IN ('0cbe0352-89b6-4ed5-8a4e-b8127d32b5b3', '80623c5b-f794-4c17-913a-88b8ac147f1c')
           AND NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM amenity_venue AS av
                  WHERE av.venue_id = v.id
                    AND av.amenity_id = a.id
               )
      );` this returned all the venues in db.

Comment: If you pass the UUIDs and not the names, use `a.id IN ...` instead of `a.name IN ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from venues where id in(
 select venue_id
 from amenity_venue
 where amenity_id in('aaa','bbb')
 group by venue_id
 having count(1) = 2
)
```

Right:

- The essential part of this is to only return venue_ids for the outer select.
- You need group by to facilitate using having.
- Having is an aggregate form of where clause.
- The having 2 makes sure both aaa **AND** bbb are present to return a venue id in the inner select, rather than the default **OR**.
- count(1) - you can use column numbers instead of asterisk or column name too for aggregate functions.

Proof the code works:

https://rextester.com/TXQB38528

I made some minor tweaks and added this version too.

```
with amenities as (select 'aaa' as amenity_id UNION select 'bbb'),
ac as (select count(amenity_id) as tally from amenities)
select * from venues where id in(
 select venue_id
 from amenity_venue
 where amenity_id in(select amenity_id from amenities)
 group by venue_id
 having count(1) = (select tally from ac)
);
```

That way you aren't constrained by maintaining counts of amenities.
You can see it here.
https://rextester.com/TKRF28879

Comment: This returns all the venues that have either a relationship with amenity `aaa` or `bbb`

Comment: `count(distinct venue_id ) = 2`

Comment: I've modified the SQL accordingly

Comment: Is there more to the query? I get this error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 11: )`

Comment: Sorry drop second ) fixed that