# How to join on a filter (input) table

Tags: sql, postgresql

So using postgres I have a function that accepts a json input parameter that I can read out into a recordset to join onto my output table. The input param is simply a list of single codes that act as filters. Lets assume my table:

```
╔═════════╦══════════════╗
║ user_id ║  Group_id    ║
╠═════════╬══════════════╣
║  1      ║ 1            ║
║  1      ║ 2            ║
║  1      ║ 3            ║
║  1      ║ 4            ║
║  2      ║ 2            ║
║  2      ║ 4            ║
║  2      ║ 6            ║
║  2      ║ 8            ║
║  3      ║ 1            ║
║  3      ║ 3            ║
║  3      ║ 5            ║
╚═════════╩══════════════╝
```

Lets say my input had the value of 1
I want to select all the users from the table who all belong to group 1. In which case the users output would be:
1, 3

Now lets say the input changed to values to 1 AND 2. That means I only want to return the users who are in groups 1 and 2. In my above example it should only return user_id = 1. 
But the way I have written my code I return all users who have groups of 1 OR 2. My code is below, I can see exactly why I am getting the wrong results but I am going for something generic so that my input can accept any given number of group ids and the results will only return the users who belong to all the group_ids passed in (its been a long week and i am sure this is simple to achieve but efficiently is my aim:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_users_filtered(p_in_filters json) 
RETURNS TABLE (user_id integer)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_user;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_user (user_id integer);

INSERT INTO temp_user (user_id)
SELECT  u.user_id
FROM    user_groups u
JOIN    json_to_recordset(p_in_filters->'data') as j(code int)
ON      u.group_id = j.code

RETURN QUERY
SELECT  tu.user_id
FROM    temp_users tu;


END;

$$;
```

I have stripped out all the gumpf from this code so it concentrates on the bit I would like to get right so ignore the fact I am using temp tables unnecessarily.

```
SELECT * FROM fn_get_users_filtered('{"data":[{"name": "male","code": "1"}]}');
```

Returns user_ids 1 and 3 - which is fine

```
SELECT * FROM fn_get_users_filtered('{"data":[{"name": "male","code": "1"},{"name":"Blonde","code":"2"}]}');
```

Returns user_ids 1, 2 & 3 because the filtering is acting like an 'OR'
I would like it to be returning just user_id = 1 who satisfies both filter values of 1 AND 2.

Comment: Perhaps you can utilise something from this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54589889/495157 In essence, you have to use having count constraint to match the number of data items. That will turn the OR into an AND...

Comment: Ah yes - that is a workable solution alright. So I have it working in that respect but maybe could be more efficient: https://rextester.com/MGRI98968

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and having.  Here is one method:

```
select user_id
from t
where group_id in (1, 2)
group by user_id
having count(*) = 2;  -- the size of the in list
```

If you wanted to have the same parameter in the `where` and `having`, then you can use arrays:

```
select user_id
from t
where t.group_id = any(array[1, 2])
group by user_id
having count(*) = cardinality(array[1, 2]);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b36e82ccd93f9d2e2ca98470c38218b8) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I effectively did:

https://rextester.com/MGRI98968

Thanks to JGFMK pointing me in the right direction!